# Customise QPushButton with an image

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qt5, qpushbutton

I am using Qt5 and having some problems in setting the back ground image of a QPushButton. I am using Qt Creator and Design to drag and drop the QPushButton. After that I created a source folder and placed an image in that directory and I googled and tried doing

```
ui->pushButton_play->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-image: url(:/source/play.png);"));
```

but no success...am I creating the folder in a wrong place?..I created in `D:\Qt5_PROJECT_NAME\source` or will I make the `url(:\\source\\play.png)`. Nothing is working...please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the images file into `.qrc` file? A URL start with `:` has indicated that It will be searched in `.qrc` file. If `.qrc` file didn't used, URL should not start with `:`. Maybe you should access the image file as

```
ui->pushButton_play->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-image: url(source/play.png);"));
```

This is [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html) documentation.

Comment: I have created the .qrc file....now how to ad dthe image....google shows all examples with old Qt creators